# How to divide a SQL table into two tables such that sum of their sizes of 2 tables is nearly equal

Tags: sql

I have a table which has two columns table_name and table_size. I want to divide this table into two halfs such that the difference of sum of table sizes is min.
Let `Table(table_name char(25), table_size int)`

```
Select * from Table gives
   T1  110
   T2  80
   T3  70
   T4  60
   T5  40
   T6   20
   T7   10
```

So I want to partition it into two tables Table1 and Table2
such that

```
Table1 should contain now (T1, T7, T2)
     Total sum = 110+ 10+ 80 = 200

Table2 should contain now (T3,T4,T5, T6) 
    Total sum = 70+60+40 + 20 = 190
```

How to do this with a SQL query ? If a general case solution is there i. e. Divide this table into m partitions and create corresponding m tables or can store tables of each partition in a list or something.

Output which I got while running query.

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum % 4 in (1, 4) then 1 else 2 end) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by table_size desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t


table_name                 table_size               seqnum grouping 
------------------------- ----------- -------------------- -------- 
T1                                100                    1        1 
T2                                 80                    2        2 
T3                                 70                    3        2 
T4                                 60                    4        2 
T5                                 40                    5        1 
T6                                 20                    6        2 
T7                                 10                    7        2 
(7 rows)
```

Comment: (1) I removed the inconsistent database tags.   Please tag only with the database you are really using. (2) Please explain the logic for separating into these groups.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Logic is something like I have a database with many tables and their sizes. Now I want to distribute load across let say m servers approximately same. So I want to divide the original table into m partitions so that each server will execute one partition and hence load is distributed. Please suggest if there is any other way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a very hard problem -- I think it is NP-complete, which is a very hard class of problems that basically requires that you search through all possible combinations.

There are approximate solutions that should work pretty well.  For instance, if you divide the rows into groups of 4 and take the 1/4 in one group and 2/3 in another that should be pretty good.

In your case:

```
select t.*,
       (case when seqnum % 4 in (1, 4) then 1 else 2 end) as grouping
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by table_size desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
```

For this particular data, the two groups are 110 + 60 + 40 and 80 + 70 + 20 + 10 -- not quite perfect but pretty close.

Comment: I chuckle every time college students have to solve NP-complete problems via SQL. It reminds me of when I had to find a number of leap years between two dates, considering that leap years were reformed like 5 times between 45 BC and 1582 AD. The script looked like [that](https://gist.github.com/laralex/f4303fef35b23d9f0213f34e0a3e6161)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I ran ur query and it gives results like I have edited in my post. I am not getting grouping as u mentioned

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Thanks a lot got the output by modifying the query.